# Python: How to partition a column only when a special character is present?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, partition

I am trying to clean up some data in a file that I have. In the column I'm trying to "clean" there is Last Name, First Name. The issue is sometimes it will come in as "#123;#Last Name, First Name".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aMW8.png)

Normally with columns like this I would use a string partition, like:

`df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.partition('#')[2]`

But in this case when I apply it to this column, it blanks out all of the names that are coming in properly as Last Name, First Name.

Is there a way to partition the values *only when* the "#123;#" before the Last Name, First Name occurs? By the way, the number "123" varies, so I wouldn't want to constrain it on specifically equaling any specific number.

Comment: Use `np.where()` to select the rows that meet the condition you want.

Comment: I tried df['Name'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains(";#",     df['Name'].str.partition('#')[2],   df['Name']) - but all that did was blank out the names with #123;#

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split('#')[-1]
```